# Puppet in DNS-less enviroment

Tags: domain-name-system, puppet

While I know DNS recommended for Puppet, is it a mandatory requirement?

Or I can get with using plain IP's for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your problem is the lack of a proper DNS server, using /etc/hosts should work, you can then use puppet for keeping /etc/hosts in sync :-)

Comment: Good idea, this suggestion can solve the matter indeed :).
I guess the only problem would be if the master puppet changes.

Still, is it possible to use just plain IP's?

Comment: possibly, but I wouldn't bother trying.  hard coding ips everywhere puts you in a world of hurt if they need to be changed.

Comment: It is hard to get puppet working in a DNS-less environment, you'll spend a lot of time fighting certificate problems.  Avoid it if you possible can.  A local DNS server isn't too hard to setup.

Comment: Yep, I'm already convinced myself I should stop thinking in "flat IP" (thanks to other great answers on this site), hence I asked to close this question.

Comment: Best to leave the question open for anyone who comes along in the future with the same problem.  You can help them even more by posting your exact rationale in a detailed answer on this question.